# How is Gödel's incompleteness theorem interpreted in intuitionistic logic?

Tags: godels-incompleteness-theorem, intuitionism

Classically, one sets up an axiomatic system with a formal deduction system & an interpretation in a model. Generally it is *sound*, that is: a formally deduced theorem is also true when interpreted in the model. The reverse is called completeness, if a sentence in the model is true then it is also formally deducible. This is the statement of [Godels completeness Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem).

Confusingly [Gödel Incompleteness Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%F6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems#First_incompleteness_theorem) refers to the notion of decidability (this is distinct to the notion of decidability in computation theory aka Turing machines and the like) - a statement being decidable when we are able to determine (decide) that it has either a proof or a disproof. If all statements in the language are decidable we call it complete. The theorem says that axiomatic systems containing PA is incomplete - that is there are always statements which we cannot find a proof or a disproof.

Now, what happens if the formal deduction system is not classical but intuitionistic? [Intuitionistic logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic) is many-valued but rather than modelling truth one models constructability/provability, which instead of using set theory semantics uses Kripke semantics. Now:

1. Is it still *sound*? That is: a formally deduced theorem is also constructible?
2. Is it *incomplete*? There is a constructible sentence that is not formally deducible?
3. Does it have undecidable statements?

Comment: Far from well read on the topic, but the [SEP page on intuitionism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) has a few mentions of the incompleteness theorem and might be helpful.

Comment: as mentioned in answers Goedle;s incompleteness theorems apply to Intuitionistic Logic **only when formalised as a kind of classical logic without LEM**, but this does not capture Intuitionism as Brewer  proposed. In essence **IL** is not just classical logic without LEM, since semantics are different not just a few changes i(i.modify a couple of rules) in syntax.

Comment: Moreover constructive manthematics **is not** just classical mathematics without Axiom of Choice (which implies LEM), but in citations this analogy is made. It embodies a different view related to semantics most importantly. In this sense having propositions which can be undecidable, effectively embeds Goede;s theorems as integral part of Intiotionism from the start

Comment: a nice post ["Gödel’s Proof and Intuitionism"](http://www.jamesrmeyer.com/ffgit/intuitionism.html) in the same direction and meaning as my previous comments ([similar question on math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/448527/are-the-godels-incompleteness-theorems-valid-for-both-classical-and-intuitionis))

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The common axiom systems for intuitionistic logic are both *sound* and *complete*. It is interpretable as an S4 [modal logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_logic) or as a weakening of [classical logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_logic) (essentially you just drop the [law of excluded middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_excluded_middle) and [double negation elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negative_elimination) and then tweak the quantifier rules).

Since it is both sound and *complete* it is *not* incomplete. The fact that they treat "truth" as something like "provability" does not bear on the situation.

Now, is intuitionistic logic incomplete? No, but neither is classical [first order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) and incompleteness tends to come with *stronger* logical systems than FOL, not weaker ones.

The question I imagine you have in mind (though I apologize for presuming to be able to read your thoughts) is whether intuitionistic/constructive *mathematics* is susceptible to incompleteness. The answer here is yes. Gödel gave the proofs in a constructively/intuitionistically acceptable manner (i.e., using only inferences they endorse) and so the result would hold for intuitionistic number theory.

It is worth noting that you don't need an arithmetic as strong as PA to fall prey to incompleteness. All that is required is a number theory which is recursively axiomatizable.

[Robinson arithmetic (Q)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robinson_arithmetic) is a theory much weaker than PA (I believe it is PA without induction) but incompleteness still arises. It might be (can't remember exactly) the weakest system still prey to the incompleteness theorems. It was actually designed to be such a weak system--- a system which can represent all and only recursive number-theoretic functions.

[Here](http://www.logika.umk.pl/llp/06/fp.pdf) is an interesting article I found on the topic--- looks like a good read. [These lecture notes](http://courses.umass.edu/phil513-klement/ln4.pdf) (again from Kevin Klement) do quite a good job of walking through Gödel's theorems if you want that. Otherwise the [SEP entry](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) @commando linked to should be helpful as well.

Comment: thanks for the references, they look useful. No need to apologise - You read my intentions correctly! I think I was confusing completeness which refers to syntax & semantics, and incompleteness which refers to solely 'formal proof' syntax only through the inference/deductive/proof system if I've read you right. Which is the standard name to use - inference/deductive/proof - they seem to all be used?!

Comment: @MoziburUllah I'm afraid that I'm not quite getting what difference you're pointing to. As far as I know, there is just one form of (in)completeness: (not) being able to formally prove every truth of your theory.

Comment: You said "it is both sound and complete it is not *incomplete*" and then "whether it is suceptible to *incompleteness*. The answer here is yes". I think its those two notions of completeness I had mixed up - simply because they have similar names.

Comment: @Dennis I find it surprising that intuitionistic logic is complete, while constructive mathematics is not, which would mean that there are additional axioms which cause the incompleteness?

Comment: @mcb This isn't actually all that surprising. (Classical) First-order logic is the language most mathematics is formalized in. First-order logic is complete, but very few mathematical theories couched in it will be. So yes, you're right, there are additional axioms you add to a base of intuitionistic logic that cause the incompleteness of constructive maths. In particular, whatever axioms you add that allow you to define an arithmetic at least as strong as Robinson Arithmetic are the axioms that will cause the incompleteness theorem to apply.

Comment: @Dennis _First-order logic is the language most mathematics is formalized in._ I think most mathematics is actually formalized in what can be called "second-order" logic, as you seriously need to quantify over function symbols rather often.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Yea, I think I somewhat overstated my case in this post. Superficially, most mathematics is cast in a first-order form and the standard semantics is a set-theoretic one where the "second-order entities" (properties, functions, relations, etc.) are treated as first-order entities -- sets of various sorts (e.g., a 2-place relation is just a set of ordered pairs, a function is just a set of ordered pairs where the first member of the pair is never related to more than one other object, etc.) (cont.)

Comment: Of course, however, the most standard semantics for Second-Order logic is set-theoretical and so this really muddies the waters. In the years since I've posted this answer I've grown somewhat puzzled as to what the first- vs. second-order logic dispute boils down to. Is a theory second-order if it is syntactically second-order but with a seemingly first-order semantics? Forget full second-order semantics and just consider Henkin semantics. That's provably reducible to first-order logic and so seems like a distinction without a difference. (cont.)

Comment: The crucial distinction might seem to be whether the semantics appeals to the notion of an arbitrary subset/property/plurality -- i.e., whether it's the full semantics for SOL. Clearly that goes beyond first-order logic. But it still isn't clear to me that it goes beyond first-order set theory, especially given that you have perfectly parallel questions to, e.g., the continuum hypothesis, in both cases -- it's just a matter of whether those questions arise for the object or metalanguage. (cont.)

Comment: I guess the only thing I'm somewhat sure of is that FOL is the better logic for capturing inferential patterns and SOL is the better logic for dealing with issues of definability and meaning. Essentially, it's the syntax-semantics divide. If you think syntactic (deductive) entailment is the end-all-be-all of logic, go first-order. If you think logic is about modeling certain concepts, especially generating categorical theories concerning these concepts, then maybe second-order logic is the way to go. (cont.)

Comment: Interspersed with all of this are difficult questions about where to draw the line between logic and math. Clearly FOL is logic, but what about a property-theoretic interpretation of Second-Order Logic? That might seem fine, but the set-theoretic interpretations have been commonly thought to veer too far in the mathematical direction (e.g., Quine on Second-order Logic as "set theory in sheep's clothing). TL;DR Philosophy remains hard.

Comment: (Final comment on these matters for now.) I'll definitely grant you that most ordinary mathematics -- i.e., everything outside of math logic and some of the rest of pure math -- things are done somewhat less formally and in a way that seems more amenable to second-order treatment (in that, as you say, they seem to quantify over functions). I don't know, however, to what extent these mathematicians conceive of themselves as working within a first- or second-order system. That isn't a skeptical worry, just a genuine bit of ignorance.

Comment: Concerning your comment, consider that most mathematicians do not use induction as a first-order schema, but rather they consider it as a single axiom that gives induction **for every property of the natural numbers**. Arguably, that is meta-logical in nature, which is somewhat like having higher-order logic with Henkin semantics. That is why most of them will call it "the axiom of induction" rather than "an instance of the axiom schema of induction".

Answer (score 10):

The two notions (completeness and incompleteness) are not opposites but very much connected (not only by Godel's name in the name of the two theorems).

Do take into account that Godel's Completeness Th of First-Order Logic is :
if a sentence is **true in all the models** of the axioms (i.e. it is a logical consequence of the axioms) then it is also formally deducible (in FOL) by the axioms.

Godel's Incompleteness Th is relative to formal systems containing "a certain amount" of arithmetic (for example : Robinson Arithmetic, that is weaker than Peano's) and says that we can find in an effective way a statement expressible in those formal systems that is "true" in the intended model (i.e. the model with domain the standard numbers and operation the standard addition and multiplication) but not deducible from the axioms.

This does not contradict the Completeness Th : the aforesaid statement is true in the standard model but is **NOT** true in some other "strange" model (there are many): this is the reason it is not deducible from the said axioms.

The arithmetical statement constructed by Godel in his proof is quite "strange", but starting from a result of Paris & Harrington (1977) has been possible, in mathematical logic, to find statements that are true (in the standard model) but not provable in Peano arithmetic and are more "natural". This was the first "natural" example of a true statement about the integers that could be stated in the language of arithmetic, but not proved in Peano Arithmetic.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit to clarify your first sentence. Along the way I also fixed some grammar and spelling. =)

Answer (score 2):

(adapted from a post of mine on MathSE)

**NOTE1**  Intuitionistic logic is **NOT** many-valued! (and in fact Goedel's name is again related to investigations in this direction)

> Are the Godel's incompleteness theorems valid for both classical and
> intuitionistic logic?

In a sense YES.

**BUT**

1. Goedel's incompleteness theorem(s) apply first to *classical logic*
2. Goedel's incompleteness theorem and its proof is *constructive* but *not intuitionisticaly constructive* ([Goedel's paper](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/h/hirzel/papers/canon00-goedel.pdf))

Why?

Goedel himself stated in his paper that the above procedure is "*constructively non-objectionable*", however

a) Goedel's reference to contructivism (intuitionism), is rather formal than actual (more detailed below)

b) variations of LEM (law of excluded middle) are used throughout Godel's proof

c) combined with the use of a diagonalisation procedure

(see also [*Gödel’s Proof and Intuitionism*](http://www.jamesrmeyer.com/ffgit/intuitionism.html) for another analysis)

> Does this apply the same to intuitionistic logic?

In a sense YES.

**BUT**

1. Goedel's **negative translation** of *classical logic* into *intuitionistic logic* is only formal ([Goedel's paper](http://www.csl.sri.com/papers/cade92-ns/cade92-ns.ps))

Why?

a) negative translation of classical logic to intuitionistic logic **is not intuitionism**, rather a *formal analogy*, because the semantics of what constitutes a construction, a proof, implication and of course the definition/construction of new entities based only on previously constructed entities is totally different, being *classical than intuitionistic* (and same holds for the original incompleteness proof, where these conditions are neither formalised nor met) (see also [Kolmogorov's Interpretation of Intuitionistic Logic as Problems](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/jmckinna/kolmogorov-1932.pdf))

b) intuitionism has, in a sense, already embedded the incompletenmess theorems as it accepts statetements which can neither be proved nor refuted (at a certain given time)

c) Brouwer himself foresaw Goedel's results by a decade at least (note: Goedel himself had attended Brouwer's lectures on the foundations of mathematics)

Quoting from [Artemov's Understanding Constructive Sematics (Spinoza Lecture)](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/Info/People/artemov/spinoza.ps)

[image]

And also from [here](http://www.math.nsc.ru/conference/malmeet/13/Artemov.pdf)

> **Intuitionistic vs. Classical Perspective**
>
> **Intuitionists** normally base their formal systems on intuition of constructive, e.g., **BHK-style** informal semantics, rather then on
> classical foundations...
>
> **Classical mathematicians** (such as Gödel, Kolmogorov, Kleene, Novikov, and others) seek a rigorous
>
> **classical definition of the constructive semantics.**

In the light of the above Goedel's incompleteness results **do indeed hold for intuitionistic logic in a formal way (with classical semantics) but not for intuitionism** (which in any case does not need any incompleteness result as they are already embedded in the practice and semantics)